# Pyhton main failing import in sub package not when sub packes is run as main

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

Im quite new to python packages. I'm currently programming in Python 3+
I have a project structure with different small files in a folder called 'Libraries' and 1 python file called Main.py.

My project structure:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVUF3.png)

I have the following import structure:

```
#Main.py
from Libraries.ATV320 import ATV320
x = ATV320()
.....

#ATV320.py
from ModbusSerial import SerialClient
class ATV320:
......

#ModbusSerial.py
import time
class SerialClient:
......
```

If I run SerialClient.py i get no errors, if i run ATV320.py I get no errors. When running main.py i get following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\public\Documents\GitHub\Project\Main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Libraries.ATV320 import ATV320
  File "c:\Users\public\Documents\GitHub\Project\Libraries\ATV320.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ModbusSerial import SerialClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ModbusSerial'
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Since the two library files work fine when executed...
When i run main.py its suddenly throws an import error?

Comment: Does it work with `from .ModbusSerial import SerialClient` (note the dot)? See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: Hey, yes that solves it for the main.py but results in error when running aTV320.py:
```from .ModbusSerial import SerialClient
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```

Comment: There are many similar questions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/407651